# What is the correct way to request this element from the DOM?

Tags: dom, gpx

I am retrieving all the coords from a gpx file, and here is a sample line from that file

```
 <gpxx:rpt lon="11.0739613" lat="47.5691700"/>
```

In IE and FireFox, the following code executes correctly:

```
var routePoints = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("gpxx:rpt");

for (var i = 0; i < routePoints.length; i++) 
 {
     routePoints[i].getAttribute("lat");
     routePoints[i].getAttribute("lon");
 }
```

Although strangely, on Chrome this code does not work, it does not seem to retrieve any info from the DOM.

On my travels for a solution I've seen 'getElementsByTagNameNS(ns,name)' but looking at the example on http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_getelementsbytagnamens.asp I haven't managed to ascertain if that is in fact of any help to me.

Any tips appreciated

Many Thanks

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your file is using namespaces, so you should use the **namespace-aware** version of this method.

- If you know the namespace of your **gpxx:** prefix, then use:

  `getElementsByTagNameNS(your_namespace, "rpt")`
- If your file doesn't use any other namespaces with **rpt** elements, then this should be enough:

  `getElementsByTagNameNS("*", "rpt")`

Comment: Thanks @wrygiel, I'll try that.

Would I be correct in thinking that 'your_namespace' in this case should be 'http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1' based on the xml header below:


         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
     <gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"         creator="MapSource 6.16.3" version="1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd">

Comment: No. "xmlns" attribute defines namespace for elements **without** any prefix. You should be looking for "xmlns:gpxx" attribute.